# How do I send a Minecraft server packet?

Tags: python, sockets, packet, minecraft

OK, so I went on http://wiki.vg/Protocol, but I don't understand how to send the packets through a socket to a Minecraft server.  I would like to know if it is possible, and if it is how, to send Minecraft packets through a Python socket to a Minecraft server, as if the socket was the Minecraft client. I want to see if there is a way to make a minecraft person appear on a server using python and make him walk in a straight line, for a certain amount of time (probably through a python for loop), than log out. Is there a python package that allows you to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'd start with [this](https://gist.github.com/1209061) which sends a packet. It's linked to from the same page you mention. Then adjust the packet ID and the data you add to the stream.

Answer (score 0):

No, as a Minecraft server is nothing but a host listening to a TCP socket.

You're better off looking for a Python TCP/sockets tutorial in general, or a Minecraft client/bot library.